# Would adding the intValue from an NSNumber alter an NSString in any way?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, concatenation

I'm building a url dynamically and needed a way to add an NSNumber's intValue to the end of it.

```
NSNumber *hatId = [NSNumber NumberWithInt:25]
NSMutableString* theUrlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[theUrlString appendFormat:@"http://www.website.com/SelectHat/%d", [hatid intValue]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:theUrlString];
```

After doing the above a simple unit test or NSLog will show the result looks valid

http://www.website.com/SelectHat/25

But my question is this - does concatenation in this way alter the NSString so it's no long a valid string like I would expect?  also is this a "good" way to build a string that needs the intValue from an NSNumber?

**Update**

I just wanted to make sure the %d inline was no problem and the NSString was as I expected it would be. The issue I'm having is a bit more complex so I'll save that for another question.  Thanks for the replies about NSURL / NSNumber / int as I'm still learning a great deal about objective-c

Comment: No need to use `alloc/init`, either. Just do `theUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"..... %d", hadId]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious why you think appending content to a mutable string would make that string invalid. If you're having a problem please share what's actually going wrong.

```
[theUrlString appendFormat:@"http://www.website.com/SelectHat/%d", [hatid intValue]];
```

Is valid and a fine way to modify a NSMutableString.

Since you're building a URL you might want to use NSURL directly instead. Look at +URLWithString:realtiveToURL: and -URLByAppendingPathComponent: as ways to build a NSURL. Those methods can be convenient because they will prevent you from accidentally creating a string ending in "SelectHat25" or "SelectHat//25" when you wanted "SelectHat/25".

Now strings and URLs aside

```
NSNumber* hatid = 25;
```

is not valid. That's creating a pointer to an NSNumber object and assigning it to an int value. You'll be looking for a NSNumber object at memory address '25' and who knows what you'll find there. You should be constructing an instance of NSNumber instead or just using an int type.

```
NSNumber* hatid = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInteger:25];

NSUInteger hatid = 25
```

Answer (score 7):

```
NSNumber *hatId = [NSNumber NumberWithInt:25]
NSMutableString* theUrlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[theUrlString appendFormat:@"http://www.website.com/SelectHat/%d", [hatid intValue]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:theUrlString];
```

The above can easily be reduced to a single line of code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.website.com/SelectHat/%d", 25]];
```

- no need to create an NSNumber unless you really want one
- no need to separately alloc/init the string
- no need to use a mutable string at all

And, no, modifying a mutable string does not make the string invalid.

Comment: If you're going to hard code the hatID you can make it even shorter: `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/SelectHat/25"];`

Comment: Yup -- I was sorta assuming there'd be a variable for the 25... but, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong

```
NSNumber* hatid = 25;
```

An NSNumber is an object. You can't just initialise it like that. Try this:

```
NSNumber *hatId = [NSNumber NumberWithInt:25]
```

As for your question - an NSString is an NSString as long as you create it properly. But, is there any reason the number is being kept as an NSNumber instead of as a string?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think this would produce an "invalid" string? Using the appendFormat method simply extends the mutable string as required.

In terms of whether it's a good way to build a string - if you have all of the information up front, you could simply create a new (non mutable) string via the initWithFormat method. That said, there's nothing wrong with what you're doing. (That said, there's no need to use an NSNumber - a standard int would do. You're also not initialising the NSNumber correctly as @Abizern has illustrated in his answer.)